# Python: Replace an element in a list with an element from another

Tags: python, list

I have a list that is however many cells a user inputs. So say the user inputs 4, the list will consist of 4 0's: `list_1 = [0,0,0,0]`.

Now the user is also asked which of these zeros he wants to replace with a 1 (must pick 2) and enters: `1 2`. I want `list_1[1]` and `list_1[2]` to change from 0 to 1.

I have tried a few different things, but none are giving me the expected out put which should be a list `[0,1,1,0]` (if i was using the above code)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Attach the code please.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
num_zero = int(input("Please enter the number of 0s")) #note this is python3
list_1 = num_zero*[0] #creates a list with the inputted number of zeroes
indices = input("Enter list indices: i j") #get string with two numbers in it sep by space
indices = indices.split(" ")  # create array with number strings
for s in indices: 
    i = int(s) #turn each number string into an int
    list_1[i] = 1 #set the specified indices of the list of zeroes to 1
```

Comment: why so many downvotes? Marion and I gave OP what they asked for

Comment: I have no idea why people act like this? just click on downvote and go no reasons mentioned even to correct if its wrong.

Comment: It's especially annoying when both of our code works perfectly... and answers the OP's question

Answer (score 0):

```
num_zero = input('Enter number of zeros you want in a list:')
zero_list = [0 for i in range(num_zero)]
indices = raw_input('Enter the indices you want to convert separated by space:')
index_list = map(int, indices.split())
for i in index_list:
    zero_list[i] = 1
```

Comment: Please explain your answer instead of just dumping a code snippet.